# Access to Excel opened by the web application using selenium

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java

I would like to know if it's possible to access an opened Excel (opened by web application during the test and not saved to the PC yet) in test runtime, using java-selenium.

I know that Apache POI is useful with Excel but I don't want to save the Excel doc, only check values...

I'm looking for something similar to this and it should work for UFT frameworks.

```
Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selenium can only control your browser. It cannot control Excel tool. If you somehow manage to open excel spreadsheet from your web page, you will probably be able to control your Excel tool (including reading the content) using [COM technology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model).

For doing that you would need Java-COM bridge. Check [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3547587/how-to-choose-a-java-com-bridge) for details.

However I am not sure this is easier than just saving your spreadsheet and parsing it from your hard drive.

Comment: thanks a lot for the info Alexey.
yes, looks more easy save it (using AutoIt for ex)  and then, read it.